# Is Django's Caching Framework per user or across all user's

Tags: django, caching, django-cache

I have read through Django's caching framework documentation (https://docs.djangoproject.com/en/3.1/topics/cache/#), and want to know if the caching is per user or for all user's.

For example,

User A: Generates this link with parameters --> https://example.com/?parameters=hello

User A: Re-opens the previous link and experiences a fast reload.

User B: Opens the link User A generated, but does not experience a fast reload time.

No where in the documentation does it state it's per user, but from testing it seems to be that way. I just want to know if this is the intended purpose behind the caching framework?

If, so is there a way to cache the requests across for all user's?

EDIT:

I have DEBUG=False, and I implemented 3 of Django's caching techniques.

1. Dummy cache for local
2. Filesystem caching for production
3. cache_page decorator for a specific view

All testing is done on the production side.

Comment: Did you test this with `DEBUG=True`? When that is set a new thread is created per request. The cache is only for a thread so testing this on a development server would not give any accurate results.

Comment: How have you implemented?

Comment: I updated my question.

Comment: @anon Django's cache is not per user the fact that your User A experiences a fast reload and user B does not is most likely due to [Downstream caches](https://docs.djangoproject.com/en/3.1/topics/cache/#downstream-caches) like the users browser.

Comment: So, it seems it's intended to work across all user's, but it's not when I test.  thanks for the clarification @AbdulAzizBarkat

Comment: Do you want all users to share the cache of this page?

Comment: @BernardoDuarte, Yes, that would be ideal. However, my main issue is finding out whether it's intentional for the Django cache framework to cache per user.